# Is there a way in MEF for a composed object to get a pointer to the ObjectComposer used?

Tags: c#, .net, mef

trying to put up a nontrivial MEF application.

I wonder - is there a way for an object being composed to get a pointer to the ObjectComposer used to compose it?

The scenario is that the obejct may have to make inner compositions. I can push all links so far wia IMPORT attrobites on properties or the constructor, but I miss a way for the composed object to get the object composer (so it could create a sub-composer for it's inner items).

Any standard / best practice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "ObjectComposer", you mean the MEF container. I am not aware of a class or concept named `ObjectComposer` .

(**edit**: the [CompositionContainer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer.aspx) now explicitly mentions that you shouldn't put a container in itself. Hence the strike-through below.)

<strike>In your application start-up code, the container could register itself in itself:</strike>

```
CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(...);
container.ComposeExportedValue<ExportProvider>(container);
```

Then you could import it anywhere like this:

```
[Import]
public ExportProvider Composer { get; set; }
```

However, what you are asking for here is a Service Locator, which has [certain disadvantages](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). It is better to import more specific services, like an abstract factory.

[`ExportFactory`](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PartCreator) could also be helpful here, but that didn't make it into the .NET 4 release. You'll have to use the latest [codeplex release of MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com) if you want to try that.

Comment: Yes, that was it. If i do what you asked for, the composed parts can resolve their composition container. I need this mostly for services which then create sub-containers and must be able to compose their inner parts.... so they must get pretty much a reference to the composition container ;) And I would love to use MEF injection for this as a general pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

Lots of my Exporters Import IMain.

```
[Import(typeof(IMain))]
public IMain Main { get; set; }
```

IMain is used as a container for an event service and the original composition service.

```
public interface IMain
{
    ICompositionService CompositionService { get; set; }
    EventPublisher Events { get; set; }
    // more...
}
```

The initial composition is like this:

```
AggregateCatalog Catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
Catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(Application.StartupPath));
CompositionContainer Container = new CompositionContainer(Catalog);
this.CompositionService = Container;  // <- here I'm setting the IMain composition service
Container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Then when I want to compose a new object, I just pass it to the composition service:

```
MainPanel discoverPanel = new MainPanel();
Main.CompositionService.SatisfyImportsOnce(discoverPanel);
discoverPanel.Show();
```

Comment: Yeah, handcoded. I would have thought that there is an ObjectComposer export somewhere WITHIN (!) MEF that allows me to import the current object composer. Especially when dealing with hierarchies this makes sense. HIerarchies as in "I am having a composition service, the items it composes open a sub composer fror hteir own needs etc."